# jQuery form focus event

Tags: jquery, forms, focus

I've been  reading this book: Javascript & jQuery the missing manual, the on page 265 I get this code that applies a form focus event, but for some reason it does not do what is expected.

I'm sure the solution is very simple an for pros like the people in here should just take a couple of minutes to figure out.

I've tried to search for a similar example on the forum but haven't had the luck to find it:

Here's the code

```
    $('#username').focus(function() {
        var field = $(this);
        if (field.val()==field.attr('defaultValue')) {
            field.val('');
        }
   });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should also show us the html :)

Comment: What is it exactly you expect this code to do and what do you see it do instead?

Comment: Sorry guys, I finally figured it out

The code works just fine.

Thanks anyways

Comment: You should delete the question if it serves no purpose.